# SetForegroundWindow does not exactly work like Alt-Tab (I am NOT trying to steal focus!)

Tags: windows, winapi, focus

I want to transfer input focus to an application the same way Alt-Tab does.
It is a situation where `SetForegroundWindow` is allowed (i.e. I am not trying to steal focus, the trigger is a user interaction in another application).

Particulary, the application should be restored if it was minimized, come to the foreground, and give input focus to the window that previously held input focus before the user switched away.

The "Activate" is implemented in the app that should receive input focus. `SetForegroundWindow(mainWindowOfMyApp)` works if the input focus was on a direct child window of the main window.

However, if focus was on the child window of a non-modal popup, focus is not returned to that window, but still to the main window's child.

I guess the issue is that with SetForegroundWindow I'm specifically saying *set focus to this window*, rather than *...to whatever window had the focus before you tabbed away*.

I guess I could remember the last-focused window when I receive an `WM_ACTIVATEAPP (wParam==FALSE)`, and restore focus to that window when re-activating. This does not sound like the proper method, since the system seems to do that already, and there might be scenarios where this is insufficient or wrong.

Is there an alternative to `SetForegroundWindow`that behaves more like Alt-TAB?

Comment: Can I think  that your problem is to switch the focus of the pop-up non-modal window to the main window? After my test, when using `SetForegroundWindow(mainWindowOfMyApp)` on a non-modal child window, the main window does not get the focus. To be more precise, the main window will flash once. As far as I know, even using alt-tab cannot do this.

Comment: Well, I *want* the focus to end up where it was before the user alt-tabbed away (So yes, `SetForegroundWindow()` probably is the wrong API to begin with). `SetForegroundwindow(nonModalPopup)` doesn't work for me either - I wouldn't expect it too

Comment: What type of non-modal child window you created? Button? Static? Or a custom child window?  I found that the focus can be switched in a custom non-modal child window.